# Нужно найти значение он начала строки до первого пробела

Tags: java, android

У меня есть edit text  который хранит (0.000003 Total Supply 50) 
я хочу вытянуть из него  0.0003 то есть от начала и до первого пробела 
делаю это так

```
EditText el4 = (EditText) findViewById(editText4);

String st4 = el4.toString();

    int start1 = st4.indexOf("");
    if (start1 == -1) { // если не нашли
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Impossible to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

     int end1 = st4.indexOf(' ', start1 + 1);
    if (end1 == -1) { // если не нашли
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Impossible to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

     st4.substring(0, end1);
```

Но так не получается

---

ааа неработает

```
    EditText el4 = (EditText) findViewById(editText4);
String st4 = el4.toString();

        String[] parts = st4.split(" ");
        String res = parts[0];


        el4.setText(res);
```

Comment: Что означает "не получается"?

Comment: выводит все тоже самое (ничего не сокращает )

Comment: Результат substring неплохо бы присвоить чему-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EditText el4 = (EditText) findViewById(editText4);

String st4 = el4.getText().toString();
int end = st4.indexOf(' '); // ищем индекс первого пробела
if (end == -1) { // проверяем найдено ли (-1 = не найдено)
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Impossible to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
// вырезаем кусок строки от начала (0) до найденного
// и присваиваем переменной result
String result = st4.substring(0, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сплит по пробелу и первый элемент результата:

```
String[] parts = st4.split(" ");
String res = parts[0];
```

Comment: прошу прошения (я мясо )куда это дописать?

Comment: Вместо того, что написано у вас.

Comment: вместо  int start1 = st4.indexOf("");  и int end1 = st4.indexOf(' ', start1 + 1); ??

Comment: Да. В res будет сохранен текст до первого пробела.